# Selecting first item in ComboBox from ODATA call. UI5

Tags: combobox, sapui5

I have a combo box that gets populated by an odata call.

From the home page, I navigate to a page with this combo box, and I want this combo box to select the first item of of an ODATA call as the default/selected item.

I use bindAggregation to populate my Combo Box in the `onInit()` function

After the object is bound, I want to read the list and take the first one and select it.

```
bindComboBox: function() {
    var comboBox = oView.byId("ComboBoxID");
    comboBox.bindAggregation("items", {
        path: path,
        parameters: param,
        sorter: sorter,
        template: template,
        filters: filter,
        events: {
            dataReceived: this.selectFirstItemFunction()
        }
}


selectFirstItemFunction: function() {
    var comboBox = oView.byId("ComboBoxID");
    var comboBoxItems = comboBox.getItems(); // This ends up being undefined.
    comboBox.setSelectedItem(comboBoxItems[0]);
}
```

When I'm doing this, `var comboBoxItems` in `selectFirstItemFunction()` is always empty/undefined.

I also tried putting `selectFirstItemFunction()` inside `onAfterRendering()` and that didn't work either.

If the page is already loaded, and I do `selectFirstItemFunction()` then the combo box works as intended.

Any thoughts on how to get the combo box loaded up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not attaching the "selectFirstItem" function to the event. You are directly calling it when executing the "bindComboBox".

Correct it with this:

```
dataReceived: this.selectFirstItemFunction.bind(this)
```

But be careful, because "dataReceived" may not be fired if the data is already cached. So maybe you want to use the "change" event

```
change: this.selectFirstItemFunction.bind(this)
```